# Connect to VPN using command line results in error 691

Tags: command-line, vpn, batch-file

I've wrote a simple batch file to connect to a specific VPN connection using **RASDIAL**

```
rasdial MyVPNConnection
```

but it always returned the error

> 691  Access denied because username and/or password is invalid on the
>   domain.

[Remote Access Service (RAS) Error Code List](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163111)

then i tried pointing to my **Remote Access Phonebook (Rasphone.pbk)** and see what happens

```
rasdial MyVPNConnection /phonebook:%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk
```

and still there was an error 691.

I've then unchecked the following

[image: VPN Options tab]

but still the same problem was reported when executing my batch file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was that my VPN connection was using **Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol (SSTP)**

[image: VPN Security tab]

and RASDIAL can't connect to such VPN connection as:

> RASDIAL.EXE provides unattended dialing. It does not support the
>   following features available in RASPHONE.EXE: prefix/suffix,
>   auto-redial, change password, retry authentication, statistics,
>   operator assisted dialing, and connections requiring Terminal mode
>   input.

[RASPHONE and RASDIAL: Tips and Differences](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125393)

After i've figured that out i've used **RASPHONE** to make a connection passing the location of my **Remote Access Phonebook (Rasphone.pbk)**

```
rasphone -d MyVPNConnection -f %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk
```

And everything worked fine.

To disconnect you can still use **RASDIAL**

`rasdial MyVPNConnection /disconnect`

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to the phonebook file works pretty well too.

%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk

[Screenshot of shortcut and what it opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikM5P.jpg)

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.