# How to create a vpn with the cmd

Tags: vpn, cmd.exe

How can i create a batch file to create a vpn connection , so that when the computer restarts the vpn connection is not available. I tried (rasdial "vpn" username password /phone:servername /phonebook:phonebookfile ), and create a custom rasphone.pbk file ,but it always gave error "720". The normal (rasdial "vpn" username password) gives error 619 ,even if i am able to connect to it from the network icon in the notification area. Please help? Thanks in advance for answers.
my error is 619 not 691 and i tried the setting it to pptp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to VPN using command line results in error 691](http://superuser.com/questions/486741/connect-to-vpn-using-command-line-results-in-error-691)

Comment: his error was 691 mine is 619

Comment: Then it's a duplicate of [Error 619 when trying to connect with Windows VPN client](http://superuser.com/questions/523170/error-619-when-trying-to-connect-with-windows-vpn-client). Please search before asking.

Comment: he cannot connect via the gui in windows

Comment: but, i can connect to the vpn with gui ,what i am struggling with is the rasdial command and my router is set correctly